# Codeigniter transaction

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

How transaction in codeIgniter works? can I stop once transaction and start one another?

See my example

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$a = 'UPDATE ......'; RETURN TRUE
$b = 'INSERT INTO......'; RETURN FALSE

$this->db->trans_rollback(); // I tried $this->db->trans_off();

var_dump( $this->db->trans_status() );

$this->db->trans_begin();

if ( $this->db->trans_status() === FALSE  ) {
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
} else {    
   $this->db->trans_commit();    
}
```

My first transaction will always return `FALSE` (even it is true I need to rollback it) ,now I need to close that transaction and need to start another one.

The problem is with `$this->db->trans_status()` , it always returns `FALSE` on the second transaction (even after `$this->db->trans_rollback()` or `trans_off()`).

what am I doing wrong ? Please help me.

```
I am using mySql as underlying database.
```

Comment: In `var_dump` you're using `trans_status` rather than `trans_status()`

Comment: @ExplosionPills that was a typo.

Comment: are you using `innodb` or not?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan YES.

Comment: Ok, so is your error reporting enabled in `config/database.php` and if yes what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan There is no errors.

Comment: @Red - there should be an error as long as it's returning `false`

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan , There is no error (log level = 4),also db_debug = FALSE.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan i hope that enabling db_debug will disable transactions , actually the first group of transactions is a delete query , if delete works it means that there is no relations exists else relation exists,whatever the result is i need to rollback the operations,the problem is that once transaction failed ,there is no way to reset the `trans_status` flag ,once the transaction is closed then the `trans_status` should be `true` ,other ways how we know individual results of transactions ?

Comment: @Red - Okay, as you said `second transaction is always returning false` I wanted to know why. and for enabling `debug` it will not disable the transaction. see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html in managing error section. lastly you can do manual transactions that will make you more in charge for your case.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan thats true , but if i enable `db_debug` then it will stop the execution of script  once it failed,i am currently using manual transactions.I also tried the `strict_mode` on CI,but no luck.I also checked the `trans_status` variable before running the second transaction it always returns `FALSE`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24353/discussion-between-mamdouh-alramadan-and-red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works OK now with manually setting the `trans_status`

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$a = 'UPDATE ......'; RETURN TRUE
$b = 'INSERT INTO......'; RETURN FALSE

$this->db->trans_rollback(); //First transaction ends it will return FALSE always(in my case)

$this->db->_trans_status = TRUE; // setting the trans_status manually ,so it will ignore previous attempts 

$this->db->trans_begin();


//other operations ..


if ( $this->db->trans_status() === FALSE  ) {
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
} else {    
   $this->db->trans_commit();    
}
```

Comment: `$this->db->trans_status() = TRUE;` doesn't set anything! `trans_status()` is a function/method. You cannot assign value in return context.

Comment: @machineaddict that was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need add this before transaction start:

```
$this->db->trans_strict(FALSE);
```

> By default CodeIgniter runs all transactions in Strict Mode.
>
> When strict mode is enabled, if you are running multiple groups of
>   transactions, if one group fails all groups will be rolled back.